# PyQt - emit new signals dynamically

Tags: python, pyqt, signals-slots

I have this piece of code in PyQt4:

```
def _settings_value_changed(self, key, value):
    signal_name = "%s(PyQt_PyObject)" % key.replace("/", "_")
    self.emit(SIGNAL(signal_name), value)
```

I'm trying to migrate that portion of code to PyQt5 .
We know that PyQt5 signals must be defined as class attributes, my question is: is there any way to create those signals dynamically?

Comment: As far as I know there isn't. What's your usecase?

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted doesn't seem to benefit much from using signals, so perhaps you could just refactor the code to call the slots directly instead, by using `getattr`:

```
def _settings_value_changed(self, key, value):
    getattr(self, key.replace("/", "_"))(value)
```